# How to get the opposite of a join?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am trying to get the rows that don't exist in one table where one table called schedules (match_week, player_home_id, player_away_id) and the other table called match (match_week, Winner_id, Defeated_id) are joined. The players look at their schedule and play a match. I am trying to get a list of the scheduled matches that do not exist in the match table. The IDs in the match table can be in either column Winner_id or Defeated_id.

I have reviewed a number of Stack Exchange examples, but most use "IS NULL" and I don't have null values. I have used a Join that does give the output of the matches played. I would like the matches that have not been played.

CSV - `wp_schedule_test`

```
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| ID | match_week | home_player1 | away_player1 | player1_home_id | player1_away_id |
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  1 | WEEK 1     | James Rives  | Dale Hemme   |             164 |             169 |
|  2 | WEEK 1     | John Head    | David Foster |              81 |             175 |
|  3 | WEEK 1     | John Dalton  | Eric Simmons |              82 |              23 |
|  4 | WEEK 2     | John Head    | James Rives  |              81 |             164 |
|  5 | WEEK 2     | Dale Hemme   | John Dalton  |             169 |              82 |
|  6 | WEEK 2     | David Foster | Eric Simmons |             175 |              23 |
|  7 | WEEK 3     | John Dalton  | James Rives  |              82 |             164 |
|  8 | WEEK 3     | John Head    | Eric Simmons |              81 |              23 |
|  9 | WEEK 3     | Dale Hemme   | David Foster |             169 |             175 |
| 10 | WEEK 4     | Eric Simmons | James Rives  |              23 |             164 |
| 11 | WEEK 4     | David Foster | John Dalton  |             175 |              82 |
| 12 | WEEK 4     | Dale Hemme   | John Head    |             169 |              81 |
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

CSV - `wp_match_scores_test`

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| ID | match_week | player1_id | player2_id |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  5 | WEEK 1     |         82 |         23 |
| 20 | WEEK 1     |        164 |        169 |
| 21 | WEEK 2     |        164 |         81 |
| 25 | WEEK 2     |         82 |        169 |
| 61 | WEEK 3     |        175 |        169 |
| 62 | WEEK 4     |        175 |         82 |
| 69 | WEEK 2     |        175 |         23 |
| 85 | WEEK 3     |        164 |         82 |
| 86 | WEEK 4     |        164 |         23 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

The output from the mysql query are the matches that have been played. I am trying to figure out how to list the matches that have not been played from the table Schedule.

CSV - MySQL Output

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| match_week | player1_id | player2_id |
+------------+------------+------------+
| WEEK 1     |        164 |        169 |
| WEEK 1     |         82 |         23 |
| WEEK 2     |        164 |         81 |
| WEEK 2     |         82 |        169 |
| WEEK 2     |        175 |         23 |
| WEEK 3     |        175 |        169 |
| WEEK 3     |        164 |         82 |
| WEEK 4     |        175 |         82 |
| WEEK 4     |        164 |         23 |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

MYSQL

```
select DISTINCT ms.match_week, ms.player1_id , ms.player2_id FROM 
wp_match_scores_test ms
JOIN wp_schedules_test s 
ON (s.player1_home_id = ms.player1_id or s.player1_away_id = 
ms.player2_id)
Order by ms.match_week
```

The expected output is:

CSV - Desired Output

```
+------------+----------------+----------------+
| match_week | player_home_id | player_away_id |
+------------+----------------+----------------+
| WEEK 1     |             81 |            175 |
| WEEK 3     |             81 |             23 |
| WEEK 4     |            169 |             81 |
+------------+----------------+----------------+
```

The added code I would like to use is

```
SELECT s.*
FROM wp_schedules_test s
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(select DISTINCT ms.match_week, ms.player1_id , ms.player2_id FROM 
wp_match_scores_test ms
JOIN wp_schedules_test s 
ON (s.player1_home_id = ms.player1_id or s.player1_away_id = 
ms.player2_id)
Order by ms.match_week)
```

Unfortunately, the output yields "No Rows"

Comment: Your initial text description of what you want is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS The IS NULLs in other answers use the nulls introduced by outer joins, not from the input.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings, names & line numbers & with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com' and read many hits & answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy I reviewed similar posts. Please, if you don't mind could you share the link where this question has been asked. I may need to do more research in the future.

Comment: My comments explain what to do. You wrote "get a list of the scheduled matches that do not exist in the match table". Please phrase that without specific application, column or table names like I said & google like I said. PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to achieve the desired results, joining the two tables on matching player ids (noting that player id values in `wp_match_scores_test` can correspond to either `player1_home_id` or `player1_away_id` in `wp_schedules_test`). If there is no match, the result table will have `NULL` values from the `wp_match_scores_test` table values, and you can use that to select the matches which have not been played:

```
SELECT sch.*
FROM wp_schedule_test sch
LEFT JOIN wp_match_scores_test ms 
       ON (ms.player1_id = sch.player1_home_id
        OR ms.player2_id = sch.player1_home_id)
      AND (ms.player1_id = sch.player1_away_id
        OR ms.player2_id = sch.player1_away_id)
WHERE ms.ID IS NULL
```

Output:

```
ID  match_week  home_player1    away_player1    player1_home_id player1_away_id
2   Week 1      John Head       David Foster    81              175
8   Week 3      John Head       Eric Simmons    81              23
12  Week 4      Dale Hemme      John Head       169             81
```

Note that you can also use a `NOT EXISTS` query, using the same condition as I used in the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT sch.*
FROM wp_schedule_test sch
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM wp_match_scores_test ms 
                  WHERE (ms.player1_id = sch.player1_home_id
                      OR ms.player2_id = sch.player1_home_id)
                    AND (ms.player1_id = sch.player1_away_id
                      OR ms.player2_id = sch.player1_away_id))
```

The output of this query is the same. Note though that conditions in the `WHERE` clause have to be evaluated for every row in the result set and that will generally make this query less efficient than the `LEFT JOIN` equivalent.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aKiGFBym61h3BFSBkxSFQ3/1)

Comment: Yes this did answer my question. I have so much more to learn.

Comment: @ItsEricJS Good to hear. it's generally good to close questions by marking them accepted if they have been answered. That makes them rank more highly when others search for similar questions.

Comment: Got it!!  Awesome